# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Google' despite installing with pip

Tags: python, pip, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to upload a file to google drive but for some reason, the "Google" library isn't loading even when I do `pip install Google` numerous times. What could be the issue?

[image: Error]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\clarot\pythonProject\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Google import Create_Service #pip install Google pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Google'
```

```py
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from Google import Create_Service #ERRORS OUT HERE

from pathlib import Path
downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "client_secret.json"
API_NAME = 'drive'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

folder_id = ""
file_names = ["test.rar"]
mime_types = ["application/vnd.rar"]

for file_name, mime_type in file_names:
    file_metadata = {
        "name": file_name,
        "parents": [folder_id]
    }

    media = MediaFileUpload(downloads_path+'{0}'.format(file_name), mime_type=mime_type) #

    service.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media,
        fields='id'
    ).execute()
```

Comment: Have you installed the module in a virtual environment?

Comment: How would I do this? I did `pip install Google` on the terminal under PyCharm and I tried it on cmd.

Comment: The python project called `Google` on pypi (i.e. what you get when doing `pip install google` does not provide a python package called `Google`. Where did you get this code from? I strongly suggest that whoever has written this code had a file `google.py` with some custom functions in them

Answer (score 1):

You should

```
pip uninstall google
```

because what you installed is not realated to google and only provides a `import googlesearch`, but I could not find meaningful documentation of it, as it is third-party and not from `google`

Then, you need to create a file called `google.py` in your project directory (i.e. next to your `main.py`). In there insert this code:

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

Found on [the tutorial](https://learndataanalysis.org/getting-started-google-sheets-api-in-python-part-1/) that I suspect you have been following